# $\int_{-\pi}^\pi x^{2m} \cos(nx)\,dx$

Tags: integration

Calculate $$
\int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi} x^{2m}\cos(nx)\,dx$$ where $m$, $n$ are positive integers.
Help me please.

Comment: Change of variables y = nx and then try integration by parts. I'm not sure if that works but looks like it could

Comment: I try integration by parts, but this led to a dead end

Comment: Maybe you can try $\cos(n x)=\frac12\left(e^{-inx}+e^{inx}\right)$, and integrate by parts, though you'll eventually get $\int x^n e^{a x}dx$, which is non-elementary.

Answer (score 3):

Call the integral $I_{m,n}$. Integrate by parts:
\begin{align}
I_{m,n}&=\frac1n\left[x^{2m}\sin nx\right]_{x=-\pi}^\pi
-\frac{2m}n\int_{-\pi}^\pi x^{2m-1}\sin nx\\
&=\frac{2m}{n^2}\left[x^{2m-1}\cos nx\right]_{x=-\pi}^\pi
-\frac{2m(2m-1)}{n^2}\int_{-\pi}^\pi x^{2m-2}\cos nx\,dx\\
&=2(-1)^n\pi^{2m-1}\frac{2m}{n^2}
-\frac{2m(2m-1)}{n^2}I_{m-1,n}.
\end{align}
Also
$$I_{0,n}=\frac1n\left[\sin nx\right]_{x=-\pi}^\pi=0.$$
Therefore
$$I_{m,n}=2(-1)^n(2m)!\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}(-1)^k\frac{\pi^{2m-2k-1}}{n^{2k+2}(2m-2k-1)!}.$$

Comment: So you got a recurrent formula? How did you get the General formula out of it?

Comment: @КириллКолокольцев the usual trick of looking at a few terms and seeing the pattern